# What is the SE policy for OP to handle questions which have been deleted or put on hold?

Tags: support

If a question has been put on hold and stays there for longer time, or even gets deleted, is there any policy for me as OP to follow, if I see no way to improve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see no way to improve your question, and have already asked for advice in the Meta of the site on which you asked it, then I think your only option is for it to remain On Hold (and then Closed) until you can think of a way to improve it.

If you leave it too long then your question may be deleted via either automated (Roomba) clean up or manual voting.